# Node: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined when doing a findOneAndUpdate() inside of a find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  db.collection('students').find().toArray(function(err, students) {
    students.forEach(function(student) {
      // get lower score
      var lowerScore = Infinity;
      for (var i = 0; i < student.scores.length; i++) {
        if (student.scores[i].type === 'homework' && student.scores[i].score < lowerScore) {
          lowerScore = student.scores[i].score;
        }
      }
      // remove the lower score
      var toRemove = {
        type: 'homework',
        score: lowerScore
      };
      db.collection('students').findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: student._id }, 
        { $pull: { scores: toRemove } }
      );
    });
    db.close();
  });
});
```

And here is my output:

```
~/code/m101js/hw3-1 $ node script.js
/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:97
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
    at Collection.findOneAndUpdate (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1378:14)
    at /Users/azerner/code/m101js/hw3-1/script.js:20:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Users/azerner/code/m101js/hw3-1/script.js:7:14
    at handleCallback (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
    at /Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:590:16
    at handleCallback (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:234:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:424:3)
    at nextFunction (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:586:7)
    at Cursor.next (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:614:3)
~/code/m101js/hw3-1 $
```

`script.js:20:33` is referring to the point right before the `findOneAndUpdate()`. I don't see why this would cause a problem though. What's going on here?

(Note: this is part of homework 3-1 for the class [MongoDB for Node.js Developers](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about))

Edit: output when passing an empty callback to `findOneAndUpdate()`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null
    at Collection.findOneAndUpdate (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1378:14)
    at /Users/azerner/code/m101js/hw3-1/script.js:20:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Users/azerner/code/m101js/hw3-1/script.js:7:14
    at handleCallback (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
    at /Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:590:16
    at handleCallback (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:234:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:424:3)
    at nextFunction (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:586:7)
    at Cursor.next (/Users/azerner/code/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:614:3)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related but `findOneAndUpdate` won't execute unless you pass it a callback function.

Comment: Well, check the `sort` option for `findOneAndUpdate` in mongoose docs. If multiple documents are found with given conditions, `sort` provided in options parameter is used so it might be related too.

Comment: @mostruash I added an empty callback to `findOneAndUpdate` and it lead to similar output. I added it to the answer. Also, I'm not using mongoose.

Comment: findOneAndUpdate is a Mongoose method, so I don't understand why you're using it if you're not using Mongoose.

Comment: @BidhanA It's also a method of the Node MongoDB driver. See [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add { w: 1 } as the argument after your $pull, this is where the driver expects to see options, and it seems that it is needed for findOneAndUpdate.

So your query would become:

```
 db.collection('students').findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: student._id }, 
    { $pull: { scores: toRemove } },
    { w: 1 }
  );
```

Comment: That worked and seems to be correct. But 1) why then does it say that the options argument is optional in [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)? And 2a) what does `{ w: 1 }` mean, and 2b) how did you know to use it?